# Android JNI - String return as random number

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

I am new to JNI and Android. I want to return a string value from native code but it returns some random number on execution. I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong.

My "ndk.c" file:

```
int Java_com_example_mayankvijh_test_1app_MainActivity_main(){
return 3;
}

jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_mayankvijh_test_1app_MainActivity_getMessage(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
  return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"HELLO");
  }
```

My MainActivity.java

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try{
        System.loadLibrary("wrapper");

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("main return =" + main());
    System.out.println("Hi " + getMessage());
}

public native int main();
public native int getMessage();
```

I have loaded the library (".so") successfully and I am able to return type jint and display in the app but somehow jstring is returning random numbers.

My native main function is returning int and is working but for my getMessage() function string is not returning

My output for getMessage() :

```
Hi -429916127
```

My Application.mk

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
```

My Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH:=$(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := wrapper

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ndk.c

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -landroid
#--llog -lz

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: use `jobject thiz` instead of `jclass cls` refer this https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni.html

Comment: I tried with both, it's returning random negative number. Currently it returned  'Hi -253755359'

Comment: `JNIEXPORT` remove this key word.

Comment: Now it's returning positive number 'Hi 97517601' but not string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have conflicting return types:

```
jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_mayankvijh_test_1app_MainActivity_getMessage(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
  return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"HELLO");
  }
```

and

```
public native int getMessage();
```

Pointer, that is returned in native code treated as integer. You should fix decaration in java to this:

```
public native String getMessage();
```

Comment: Omg, I never noticed that, I changed a method on native side but forgot to change it on java side. Stupid rookie mistake. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

**Java Side:**

```
  public class HelloJni extends Activity{

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    TextView  tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText( stringFromJNI() );
    setContentView(tv);
}

public native String  stringFromJNI();
public native String  unimplementedStringFromJNI();  
static {
    System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
  }
 }
```

**Native Side:** file name `hello-jni.c`

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

/* This is a trivial JNI example where we use a native method
 * to return a new VM String. See the corresponding Java source
 * file located at:
 *
 *   apps/samples/hello-jni/project/src/com/example/hellojni/HelloJni.java
 */
jstring
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                  jobject thiz )
{
#if defined(__arm__)
  #if defined(__ARM_ARCH_7A__)
    #if defined(__ARM_NEON__)
      #if defined(__ARM_PCS_VFP)
        #define ABI "armeabi-v7a/NEON (hard-float)"
      #else
        #define ABI "armeabi-v7a/NEON"
      #endif
    #else
      #if defined(__ARM_PCS_VFP)
        #define ABI "armeabi-v7a (hard-float)"
      #else
        #define ABI "armeabi-v7a"
      #endif
    #endif
  #else
   #define ABI "armeabi"
  #endif
#elif defined(__i386__)
   #define ABI "x86"
#elif defined(__x86_64__)
   #define ABI "x86_64"
#elif defined(__mips64)  /* mips64el-* toolchain defines __mips__ too */
   #define ABI "mips64"
#elif defined(__mips__)
   #define ABI "mips"
#elif defined(__aarch64__)
   #define ABI "arm64-v8a"
#else
   #define ABI "unknown"
#endif

    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !  Compiled with ABI " ABI ".");
}
```

**Update:**

```
jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_mayankvijh_test_1app_MainActivity_getMessage(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
return  (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"HELLO");
}
```

Comment: tried with both, it's returning a random number. Just to add I am able to return int with and without using 'JNIEXPORT'

Comment: @MayankVijh are you trying like above

Comment: Please check the edit. I think so it is the same as you mentioned. I am creating a 'wrapper.so' and using it.

Comment: post your android.mk file exits in jni folder

Comment: if you cant find it post your gradle file of your app

Comment: @MayankVijh update you ndk.c with my answer updated section.

Comment: Still the same, I don't think so just declaring an extra variable will make the difference. Does it effect somehow? I am not sure about this stuff.

Comment: what actually is happening it is returning you its pointer address not its value. go for this tutorial https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-jni